Connect to a remote Android emulator
I have emulators running on a remote PC. To connect to the emulator, I enter the command "adb tcpip 5555" on the remote computer and then forward the port using "adb forward tcp:5552 tcp:5555".
When attempting to connect from my computer using the command "adb connect :5555", I receive the error message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
I expect to successfully connect to several emulators that are on remote computers.
The emulator was created by Android Studio. “Pixel 3Xl” version 8.0
The emulator is in developer mode.
In summary, I am having trouble connecting to an emulator that is running on a different computer. Both computers are running Windows.
I would appreciate some assistance, please 

adb forward only works within an established adb connection to an Android device, not between two PCs or an emulator running on a PC.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi, if I use adb connect :5555 and in the remote pc the emulator listens on port 5555 it should work fine? Note: in the remote PC I can run adb connect localhost (locally) and it works fine. So why is from remote it not working?

Because emulators only listen on localhost interface, remote usage is not intended as this would be a security risk. Check the command-line switches of the emulator if you can specify the interface it is listen on.

Take a look at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/tools/android/adb_remote_setup.sh.
It will help you achieve what you want.
